# Prolog Predicate findall/3 and member/2 Issue

Tags: prolog

Basically, have a series of facts in my Knowledge base regarding PopStars and their most successful years (see below).

```
popStar('Jackson',1987,1991).
popStar('Jackson',1992,1996).
popStar('Michaels',1996,2000).
popStar('Newcastle',2000,2007).
popStar('Bowie',2008,2010).
```

I need to create a predicate that takes a single parameter that is true if the name of the popStar is recognized and, if a variable is used instead, it would produce backtracking, without any duplicates. Originally I started off with something very simple (see below).

```
  ispopStar ().
  ispopStar (H) :-  popStar (H,_,_).
```

But then figured out that any backtracking would include duplicates ('Jackson' mentioned twice). So, looking to create a list using findall/3 and then use member to check whether the popStar is a valid one.

However, whenever I attempt to use the member predicate on the list I've created from the facts, it would always result in an non-stopping, ever expanding list. I think it could well be a noob error as I've only just started learning prolog. Would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code below and could see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

**Findall/3**

```
   findall(V,popStar(V,B,N),X)
```

**Result**

```
   X = ['Jackson', 'Jackson', 'Michaels', 'Newcastle', 'Bowie']
```

**Member/2**

```
   member('Newcastle',X).
```

**Result**

```
   339 ?- member('Newcastle',X).
   X = ['Newcastle'|_G2881] ;
   X = [_G2880, 'Newcastle'|_G2884] ;
   X = [_G2880, _G2883, 'Newcastle'|_G2887] ;
   X = [_G2880, _G2883, _G2886, 'Newcastle'|_G2890] ;
   X = [_G2880, _G2883, _G2886, _G2889, 'Newcastle'|_G2893]
```

**Update**

I've had a play around but still very stuck. I'm using the following predicate below to create a list of unique entries;

```
  setof(Name,X^Y^popStar(Name),Names)
```

And then using the following predicate for the existence of an element (example below).

```
 setof(Name,popStar(Name),Names), member('Jackson',Names).
```

From the predicate above, it returns a value of;

```
 Names = ['Jackson'].
```

But really, I would expect it to return true, as 'member' certifies whether a specific elements is within a list. Also, when I try to insert a variable into member (so that it backtracks through all of the available popStars, I receive the following message).

```
setof(Name,popStar(Name),Names), member(X,Names).

Names = ['$VAR'('X')].
```

Would really appreciate some help by showing me what to do in this example. I'm really stuck so really appreciate it.

Comment: `setof(Name,popStar(Name),Names), member('Jackson',Names).` is going to succeed ("return true" as you call it) and show you what it came up with for the variable `Names`. That's how it works. And can you explain what you mean by, *when I try to insert a variable into member*, and what you're trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other more subtle problems with your approach, but first the obvious problem.

Queries on the top level **do not share variables** between each other. Each new query has new variables, even if they use the same name!

```
?- X = foo.
X = foo.

?- X = bar.
X = bar.

?- X = 3.
X = 3.

?- X == 3.
false.
```

You need to make a *conjunction* of subgoals!

```
?- L = [a,b,c,b], member(a, L).
L = [a, b, c, b] ;
false.

?- L = [a,b,c,b], member(b, L).
L = [a, b, c, b] ;
L = [a, b, c, b].
```

As you see, this is still not what you are after.... If a list has an element occurring twice, `member/2` succeeds twice, and this is exactly what you don't want.

You could consider using `memberchk/2` instead. If you compare the documentation on `member/2` and `memberchk/2` you should see how they differ in semantics and intended use. In short, if you already have a list that does not contain any variables, and you only want to *check* if that list contains a certain element, it is OK to use `memberchk/2`:

```
?- L = [a,b,c,b], memberchk(a, L).
L = [a, b, c, b].

?- L = [a,b,c,b], memberchk(b, L).
L = [a, b, c, b].
```

This gets more hairy if any of the two arguments to `memberchk/2` is not ground. Look at this:

```
?- memberchk(X, [a,b,c]).
X = a. % No more solutions!
```

So, this is not a good way to solve your problem.

It is maybe better to use `setof/3` instead of `findall/3`. To simplify a bit, say you have a table `foo/1` that looks like the list from the example above:

```
?- listing(foo).

foo(a).
foo(b).
foo(c).
foo(b).

true.

?- findall(X, foo(X), Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c, b].
```

Then:

```
?- setof(X, foo(X), Xs), member(Y, Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c],
Y = a ;
Xs = [a, b, c],
Y = b ;
Xs = [a, b, c],
Y = c.

?- setof(X, foo(X), Xs), member(b, Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

You would have to probably tell Prolog not to bind the second and third argument to `pop_star/3` when you use `setof/3`, so it would go something along the lines of `setof(Name, X^Y^pop_star(Name, X, Y), Names)`.

Comment: Hi @Boris .. have had a go but still no luck - have posted an update to my original post - would really appreciate any further help you could provide

Comment: @SamNeeds You are still not using `setof/3` properly: with a bit of reading on your own you should be able to figure it out. The predicate you have defined, `popStar/3`, has 3 arguments; when _you_ give it to `setof/3`, you write it with one argument. If you typed it in as I showed in my answer, with 3 arguments, it must definitely give you what you need.

Comment: yeah thank you - managed to figure out most of it now - thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry - have always thanked people for their contributions. Will mark your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SamNeeds thanking is polite; votes and accepts is how questions and answers become useful to others too.